# Docker mongo image 'Connection refused' from other container

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, boot2docker

I'm new to docker. I'm trying to create a MongoDB container and a NodeJS container. My file looks:

```
version: '2'
services:
  backend:
    image: node:5.11-onbuild
    ports:
     - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
     - .:/code
    working_dir: "/code"
    links:
     - mongodb
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:3.3
    expose:
     - 27017
```

It should run `npm install` and then `node .`.
But `docker-compose up` ends up with `[MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]` while the command `node .`.
I think this is because of the `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` in the file `/etc/mongod.conf`. Is this right?

I use boot2docker on a Win10 system.

How can I solve this problem so that node can connect to the MongoDB?

Comment: deadlink in a question, consider fixing plz

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Thanks. Fixed it.

Comment: This will help you: [use docker stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32503116/nodejs-mongodb-in-docker-compose-econnrefused/56017282#56017282)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

In your backend app, connect to `mongodb:27017` instead of `127.0.0.1:27017`. Where 'mongodb' is the name of your *service* within docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. Instead of the IP we use the link name inside a docker container. Thanks!

Comment: For clarification for other people having the issue.  Within your node app: ```mongoose.connect('mongodb://db:27017/whatever');```  Where 'db' is the name of your container within docker-compose.yml - i.e. ```depends_on: - db  db: image: mongodb```

Comment: @colby jax I am using mongoose.connect() as u mentioned. But I am getting error when I use docker-compose up

Comment: this gives me ENOTFOUND mongodb mongodb:27017

Comment: Even i'm facing the same error and i couldn't find any workaround/fix for this yet. Please let us know

Comment: i use my container name for that but it does not works

Comment: @a_m_dev it should be the docker compose service name. I fixed my answer

Comment: It's the name of the container which will replace ```localhost```. i.e. ```mongodb://your_mongodb_container_name:27017/```. You can check this container name using the command ```docker ps -a``` in your console

Comment: yes "localhost" -> should be replace with container name which is "mongo"

Answer (score 16):

I recently encountered similar issue. I am running docker toolbox under win 10 and this is how it worked for me:

1) I had to verify which URL my default docker machine is using. This can be checked by running `docker-machine ls` command. It will list available machines:

```
NAME             ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default          *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:1234           v17.06.0-ce
rancher-client   -        virtualbox   Stopped                                       Unknown
rancher-server   -        virtualbox   Stopped                                       Unknown
```

2) When running mongodb image specify the port mapping

```
docker run -d -it -p 27017:27017 mongo
```

3) At that point the valid mongo url would look something like this

```
var dbhost = 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/test
```

where `192.168.99.100` was the default machine URL from the point 1)

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: I do not have the `docker-machine` command available, but I managed to check the address of my mongo image using `docker inspect mongo`, where mongo is the name of the instance

Comment: @Marcin

 I built one image (sample nodejs application)
 when I try to run that application with my localdb. I am getting error.I followed ur steps ..
docker run -d -it -p 27017:27017 mongo this is for running mongodb
 I am running the nodejs application by
docker run -d it -p 8088:8088 nitikishu/samplenodejs 

now I want to connect mongodb with my application 
what command should I run
In my docker ip address 192.168.99.100:8088 my application is running but mongodb is not working in localhost:27017 this message is displaying.

Comment: and It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
Now what should I do?
using which host and command to connect the mongodb with the application

Comment: @Marcin var dbhost = 'mongodb://192.168.99.100:27017/test will it connnect the db?

Comment: i was able to find the `IPAddress` of my mongo docker using `docker inspect mongo-container` command, and using `IPAddress` it worked, but the node.js code would need to have something dynamic name, not some hard-coded IP.
So what should be used?
i tried with `mongo-container-name`, didn't work

Answer (score 6):

Most likely, yes. 127.0.0.1 points to localhost *inside* the mongodb container, so is not accessible from outside the container. Binding to 0.0.0.0 will probably work.

With the link you specified in the docker-compose.yml, your backend container should then be able to connect to the mongo container through `mongodb:27017`

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell the container to use it's own IP Address instead of localhost.

For example, let's assume you generated scaffold code with `expressjs`, you have to write in `routes/index.js`

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
router.get('/thelist', function(req, res){

  // Get a Mongo client to work with the Mongo server
  var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

  // Define where the MongoDB server is
  var url = 'mongodb://172.17.0.5:27017/dbname';

  // Connect to the server
  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
  .........
```

where `172.17.0.5` is the `$CONTAINER_IP`

you can find the container ip via

`$ docker inspect $CONTAINER_HOSTNAME | grep IPAddress`

If you still can't understand you can take a peek at my [Docker NodeJS and MongoDB app](https://github.com/dminca/nomon)

Answer (score 0):

I've changed

`mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/admin`

to

`mongodb://admin:admin@mongo:27017/admin`

and it works

Thanks for the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34711892/3841211