# Setting up a mongoDB in a Dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile, database-administration

I try to set up a mongodb in a Dockerfile.
This is from my dockerfile which is based on Debian:

```
...mongoDB is installed here
#start the mongoDB
RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
RUN mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db')"
```

When I try to build this Dockerfile I get the following error:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

It would be great, if anyone knew how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711642/docker-mongo-image-connection-refused-from-other-container/35987734) SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to how Docker processes the Dockerfile. Each statement in the Dockerfile is executed in a container, which was created from the image of the previous line. In case of the `RUN` statement, Docker runs the code in a container and creates a new image based on the current state of the container. The image does not contain any information about running processes.

In your case, this means you have an image, which contains the `mongodb` installation. Let's call it `A` (instead of hash values from the `docker build` log). The first `RUN` statement

```
RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

is processed in a container, let's call it `a`, which is based on image `A`. The process `mongod` in `a` probably appends a few lines to the log file. Once the `RUN` statement has been processed, the container's file system is frozen and labeled as image `B`. A Docker image does not contain any information about running processes. In fact, at this point, there is not `mongod` process running anymore. However, image `B` contains the log entries from this previous `RUN`.

The second `RUN` statement

```
RUN mongo --eval "use db"
```

is executed in container `b`, which is based on image `B`. This commands fails because there is no running process to which `mongo` could talk to.

I think there are two solutions to your problem:

1. In general, you can run both scripts in one step

   `RUN mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log && mongo --eval "use db"`

   or move them to a bash script, such that they are executed in the same container.
2. Use the official `mongo` [image on Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/).

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first solution works perfectly. I can run the commands chained so I don't have to use an extra bash-script.

Comment: To finally get a database the full command is `mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log && mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('db')"`. I was also wrong with second command mongo shell helpers won't work here.

Comment: Have same issue. 

I have 
FROM mongo

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron awscli

ADD run.sh /run.sh
CMD /run.sh
within Docker file and when container is up the mongodb does not start and i get the aforementioned error. Can you help?

Comment: @brankoterzic What is in your `run.sh`? Does it start the mongodb daemon?

Comment: @sauerburger No it does not. It is a script which supports mongo backup and cron job specification.

Comment: The official [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/a504b49bb5cf896fbf3640b4b8cb0d09a25b53ae/3.6/Dockerfile) contains `CMD ["mondod"]`. So when you start a container, it starts the mongodb daemon by default. If you overwrite the `CMD` in your Dockerfile, you need to start the database daemon yourself. Or, maybe you can execute `run.sh` at build-time using `RUN /run.sh` and leave the default `CMD` in-place.