# Connection between docker containers: need to put gateway instead of name of container, why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was testing things for my own and I had problem: Trying to connect a nodeexpress container(app) to a mongo container(database), I can connect to mongo from MongoCompose if I connect to `localhost:27017` but cant into the container of nodeexpress with mongoose configuration url to connect database like this `'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbtest'`.

So I look up at SO some solutions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34711642/docker-mongo-image-connection-refused-from-other-container)) and answers what I see was instead of `'mongodb://localhost:27017/dbtest'` I need to write the name of the my container `'mongodb://mymongo:27017/dbtest'`, but for me this didnt work, only recieve ECONNREFUSED error.

Containers was in the same network, here is my dockerfile and docker-compose file.

## Dockerfile

```
#node 8.16.2
FROM node:8.16.2
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

## docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
   db:
    image: mongo
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    networks:
        - testing
   app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks: 
        - testing
networks: 
    testing:
```

I **solved** this problem like this `mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/dbtest`  where `172.17.0.1` is the **Gateway** of the network that are the containers.

Can someone explain this behavior and if it is correct ?
Platform Linux

Comment: Are you on Windows or another OS?  Also are you using docker-toolbox, Docker for Windows, or something else?

Comment: @wesleyRolnick Linux

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the name `mymongo` from? You have defined the name of mongodb service as `db` in your compose file. So use the connection string `'mongodb://db:27017/dbtest'`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
   db:        ---------------> This is the name of your mongo service
    image: mongo
    ports:
        - 27017:27017
    networks:
        - testing
   app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks: 
        - testing
networks: 
    testing:
```

Comment: still not working doing that, `MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.17.0.3:27017`, its only work me with the Gateway of network.

Comment: Where is the error coming from? This should be used from inside your app container.

Comment: I use this url `'mongodb://db:27017/dbtest'` (your answer)  to connect (with mongoose) my app to database , and console still show me the error of the last comment. Only works if I use `'mongodb://172.17.0.1:27017/dbtest'`, that is the Gateway of the network.

Comment: So you are getting this error after you run `docker compose up`?

Comment: Yes, connection between database and app works only if I put the network gateway, and I want to know if this is correct and why other solutions like yours dont work to me.

Comment: Are you sure mongo container is up before the app is trying to connect to it? Can you declare that your `app` service depends on `mongo` using `depends_on` field in compose file and check if it works. You might also want to add a retry in case mongo takes time to boot up. - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on